# Variable to store Asterisk extension dialed by user

Tags: voip, asterisk, voice

I am using Asterisk for voice calling.

I am using below context If user call back-

```
[from-pstn]
exten =>  _X.,1,Playback(demo-thanks)
```

suppose my number is 74900 on which user can call back.

what I want if user call on 749001, 749002 then i could recognize what user has exactly dialed. currently when user dials 749001 then asterisk console shows-

```
Executing [74900@from-pstn:1] Playback("DAHDI/i1/usernumber-1e", "demo-thanks") in new stack
```

How can I get exact number dialed by user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in `EXTEN` variable to access the number user dialed in. Example:

```
[from-pstn]
exten => _X.,1,Playback(demo-thanks)
same => n,SayNumber(${EXTEN})
```

See [Using the CONTEXT, EXTEN, PRIORITY, UNIQUEID, and CHANNEL Variables](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Using+the+CONTEXT%2C+EXTEN%2C+PRIORITY%2C+UNIQUEID%2C+and+CHANNEL+Variables).

Comment: I tried this ...still getting result up to 74900

Comment: @HimanshuMatta, is `749001` a valid [DID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_inward_dialing) number?

Comment: Valid number is 74900 but  when someone dials 749001 then also call comes but with extension 74900 not with 749001 it's possible to get exact extension or not ?

Comment: @HimanshuMatta, I'm afraid it's not possible, because telecom service provider doesn't send `749001` to you even the user dialed it. In your case, you need setup an IVR to let user press `1` or `2` to forward call to extension `749001` and/or `749002`